# Passing C# object into vbscript

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript, adodb

Is there any way to pass a C# object( in this case I'm using ADODB.Recordset) to vbscript? Or is their a way to call a vbscript function from C# and pass in this object?

E.x. In C# I have a object called `ADODB.Connection rs` is there a way to call my vbscript function `DisplayDrillThrough(rs)` like so?

Comment: VBScript runs on the client - it has to open it's own connection/recordsets. And, really? Classic ADO in C#?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? C# can probably do it all :)

Comment: Security in VbScript is garbage. Right now I have it working entirely in VBScript but trying to make it more secure is not working at all since it pretty much doesn't exist and the only way I can actually make secure encrypted connections is through C#. Essentially I'm doing contract work and they're using Microsofts Office Web Components which I can only change/access with client side code( it won't let me change attributes server side)

Comment: Can you build and use a dll? I have no idea if this will work in vbscript, but it seems ok in vba, which is not so different.

Comment: If you need to access server-side data directly from the client - the correct way is to make AJAX (xmlhttprequest) call to server-side code. And let server-side handle all DB connections

Comment: @Fionnuala This is what I'm trying to do and seems like the best option without changing the entire code that involves OWC. Although I have made recommendations in changing the report system as Microsoft's OWC is not being supported past 2017.